# Magento 2 Retrieve store phone number

Tags: magento2, template, core-config-data

I tried using this function

```
$this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
      'general/store_information/phone',
      \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITES
    );
```

And it is always returning an null value. This is on all general store settings. Is there a way to retrive store website phone number?
Use case display store phone number in checkout.

Comment: Your issue solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The store config values **STORES > Configuration** are stored in `core_config_data` table

[image]

There are 5 columns, however, we should focus on 4 columns:

+**scope**: The scope to use to determine config value, e.g., `store` or `default`. We have some scopes:

__**Magento\Framework\App\Config::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT**

__**vendor/magento/module-store/Model/ScopeInterface.php**

```
interface ScopeInterface
{
    /**#@+
     * Scope types
     */
    const SCOPE_STORES = 'stores';

    const SCOPE_WEBSITES = 'websites';

    const SCOPE_STORE   = 'store';
    const SCOPE_GROUP   = 'group';
    const SCOPE_WEBSITE = 'website';
    /**#@-*/
}
```

+**scope_id** they are store ids. We can find these values in `store` table.

+**path**: The path through the tree of configuration values, e.g., `general/store_information/name`. When developing a module, we declare these values in `etc/adminhtml/system.xml`

+**value**: config values.

So, when we want to get the config values, we need to know `scope, scope_id` and `path`. Magento had a method to retrieve config value by path, scope and scope code (store id):

**vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php**

**vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/ScopeConfigInterface.php**

```
public function getValue(
    $path, 
    $scopeType = ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT, 
    $scopeCode = null
);
```

In your case, you want to get the phone value with `websites` scope and path `general/store_information/phone`. We should start to debug with a raw sql to check the available phone numbers:

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data a WHERE a.`path` LIKE '%general/store_information/phone%'
```

[image]

After executing this query, we make ensure that the phone number is available or not in our scope: `\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITES`. If not available in our scope, we should set in admin config.

`SCOPE_WEBSITES` correlates with scope id (store id), so we need to set scope id (store id) for `getValue()` method. For example:

```
    //Getting current store id
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    */
    ......
    $scopeCode = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId()

    $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
      'general/store_information/phone',
      \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITES,
     $scopeCode
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

Inject ScopeConfigInterface and StoreManagerInterface following way:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $storeManager;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
 */
protected $scopeConfig;


public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
) {
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
}
```

Now write following line for output:

```
$this->scopeConfig->getValue('general/store_information/phone', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $this->storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId());
```

Extra info:

For future reference: This works but if you are extending \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template don't forget to make the constructor like the parent class.

public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
array $data = []
)
{
parent::__construct($context, $data);
$this->storeManager = $storeManager;
$this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
}

And if you accessing it in phtml make the variables public instead of private.