# Magento 2 Retrieved core_config_data value is null

Tags: magento2, configuration, core-config-data, unit-tests

I am having similar problem as this [stackexchange post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125968/magento-2-retrieve-store-phone-number). I have looked that the database table `core_config_data` contains the value i need to retrieve. But `$configValue=$this->_scopeConfig->getValue(path, \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE)` query returns null. (The error outputs while running unit test "Failed asserting that null matches expected".) I have tried the module code in Magento 2.1.0 and 2.0.7 versions getting same results.

I am suspecting that the problem might be in some missing etc file in my module or settings that is needed to retrieve db value in module?

My etc contains: `module.xml`, `adminhtml/routes.xml` and `adminhtml/system.xml`.
Also `system.xml`:

```
   <field id="username" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Username</label>
    </field>
```

SQL query: `SELECT * FROM core_config_data a WHERE a.'path' LIKE '%eepohs_erply/account/username%'`
[image: sql query]

Comment: You tried a raw sql to check your value: `SELECT * FROM core_config_data a WHERE a.path LIKE '%path/value/need%'`

Comment: In your case, you can get the config value: `$this->_scopeConfig->getValue('eepohs_erply/account/username')`. Because, the scope is `default` and `scope_id` is equal to 0.

Comment: I have tried it and same result like described in question.

Comment: Tried to clear your Magento Cache?

Comment: I have tried it and same result like described in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

core_config_data is null because in unit test you use the Mock object not the real one.

For example:

```
 $this->_scopeConfig = $this->getMock('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface');
```

If you want it return the value you must add this in your unit test:

```
 $this->_scopeConfig->method('getValue')->willReturn('put_your_value_here')
```

For the real data test: I suggest you use integration test with a test database. So you can play with real data.